# Play framework external dynamic HTML handling

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, playframework-2.2

I'm developing a web application on a Play framework 2.2.0 (Scala). The application is generally taking some input from the user, and then calls external module which in turn processes the input and generates html report. The report has a rather complex structure with html, javascript and json data, all put into different files. Then I wish to be able to render this report to the user by the Play framework, without him having to download report in an archive.

I tried to put these report files to some directory in the assets, and Redirect, but this won't work in production. Then I tried to use Ok.sendFile inline, but since content depends on other files the report does not render correctly.

I wonder if there is any "intended" way to render such dynamically generated HTML to the user?

Comment: Can't the external module put JSON and JS into the source code of the HTML page ? Where does it store the additional assets ? can't you just save complete set of files to new folder and then just redirect to it? It's hard to help you when we don't know how the assets are delivered to you

Comment: No, the external module can't put all the data into single HTML, because it may be arbitrary large. The report HTML is designed to show only small chunks of that data. It stores additional data in the subfolders of the folder with index HTML. Yes, I can save complete set to a single folder (in fact that's how it works), but I just don't get how to get redirect working.